# Magento session expries while connecting through Magja

Tags: java, magento

I have a operation to disable the products in magento through java ie Magja, There are almost 17000 products which I have to disable , After disabling around 300 products in a loop I get a exception which says

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Session expired. Try to relogin
```

Can anybody tell me what shuld I do so that even if session expires ,I shuld be able to relogin to that the disabling flow does not get interrupted.